# Access /home partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, mount

I have installed 13.04 and created 2 partitions: one with ext4 journaling system `/` mount point (36GB) for songs  and other with `/home` mount point for videos (43GB) and a swap partition of 1GB. I am able to see only `/` partition and not `/home` partition. That means I cannot use `/home` partition to save videos? How to access `/home` partition also so that I would be able to use 79GB (both the partitions: `/` and `/home`) of my hard disc? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo fdisk - l` and of `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

On your install once you open the file manager are you able to go through your Downloads, Pictures, Music, Documents directory ? if so then you are on the /home partition...  Right-click on a blank area and select Properties to examine the size of the partition the folders are on...

Comment: The home folder is there in / partition via Devices -> Computer -> Home right? It says it is 36GB. I don't understand where the separate /home partition is. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: The home folder is there in / partition via Devices -> Computer -> Home right? It says it is 36GB. I don't understand where the separate /home partition is. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @user185343 well, for most people a large `/home` partition is a place for all personal data (if they go at all for separate home partition setup, some just go with a large `/` and swap), so that both songs and videos are kept there. Anyways, you may try running `fdisk -l` (this one requires `sudo`), `mount` and `df -h`, or perhaps `cat /etc/fstab`, commands from the terminal to inspect your setup. If there's something like `/dev/sda1` mounted at `/` and `/dev/sda2` mounted at `/home` (`fstab` may use UUIDs, not device names though), then it's all ok.